# Expected argument of type "string", "App\Entity\Location" given at property path "name"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Following is the code:

```
class McsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', EntityType::class,[
                'class' => Location::class,
                'label' => 'For The Location',
                'choice_label' => function(Location $location){
                    return $location->getName();
                }
            ])
            
            ->add('mcs', CollectionType::class,[
                'entry_type'=> McType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false ],
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            ]);
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // 'data_class' => '',
        ]);
    }
}
```

The Error that I'm getting is the following:

> Expected argument of type "string", "App\Entity\Location" given at
> property path "name".

To resolve this issue I tried with renaming name with location didn't worked.
When I click on the submit button, I get the above error.

Even putting the data-class didn't help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is about your `Location` class. It can't be cast to string just like that, which is expected.
So you need to implement the magic method `__toString()`:

```
public function __toString(): string
{
  return $this->name;
}
```